# Ionic3 app redirects to RootPage when I push a page

Tags: angular, ionic3, lazy-loading

I'm having trouble navigating from one page to the other in my Ionic 3 based mobile app. I have a link which calls a function named openPage when clicked in my homepage. I expect this to open a second page but it doesn't.

Here is my code:

the link from my HomePage:

```
<a color="dark" class="dashboardicons" (click)="openPage('FaqsPage')"  href="#">
    <ion-icon name="ios-information-circle-outline" color="danger"></ion-icon>
   <br>FAQs
</a>
```

home.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    openPage(page){
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);
    }

}
```

faqs.ts file (the second page)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-faqs',
  templateUrl: 'faqs.html',
})
export class FaqsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewWillLeave FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLeave FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewWillUnload() {
    console.log('ionViewWillUnload FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewCanEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewCanEnter FaqsPage');
  }

  ionViewCanLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewCanLeave FaqsPage');
  }
}
```

Every time I click on the link, the second page flashes (appears and then disappears), then I'm redirected back to the homepage. I have logged the life-cycle events of the second page and apparently the page runs through all of them. I have tried with both push() and setRoot() methods using NavController without success. All my pages are lazy loaded. What I'm I doing wrong?

The FaqsPage is a blank page at the moment. It's HTML is as follows:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Faqs</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding></ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you share code of FaqsPage?

Comment: Sorry you still did not share code that calls your method for page change. Please share all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setRoot` in `NavController` it sets the new page as the root page. use `push` instead `setRoot`.

```
openPage(page){
    this.navCtrl.push(page);
}
```

Comment: the app behaves the same when I use push function

Comment: @Muya George Can you reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xaa1ee. Then I can give a solution.